# Basic combinatoric problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm working on this problem and am not sure where to go next.  The problem is:

A student is given a true-false test with 10 questions.  If she gets seven or more correct, she passes.  If she is guessing, what is the probability of passing the test?

My attempt:

1) I see that order is important, and T/F answers can be used with replacement.  So, that gives me n^r possible answer combinations:

n = 2 and r = 10

2^10 = 1024 possible answers

So, I see that the probability of her getting a 100% on the test is 1/1024.

But, I'm not sure what to do next to find out the probability of her getting a 70% (7 out of 10) correct.  I assume it would be the number of possible combinations where 7 of 10 answers are correct, divided by 1024, but how do I find that number?  Is it 2^7 = 128 and thus 128/1024?

What do I do?

Comment: Think about 9/10. In how many ways can she fail just one?

Comment: Why would it be? If you have ten questions and you need to answer exactly one question wrong, in how many ways can you do this?

Comment: There would be 10 ways to answer 1 question wrong.

Comment: 24 ways to get 2 questions wrong.  I found this by counting.  I'm still drawing a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the problem in the following way: Let's denote correct answer as $H$ and incorrect answer as $T$ (Think "Heads" and "Tails" in random coin tossing).

To pass we need 7 or more $H$. Equivalently, 3 or less $T$.

Now This follows a binomial distribution with $n=10,p=1/2$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: 10! / (7! * 3!) = 120       - so there are 120 ways to form combinations of 7 from 10.  If I take 120 / 1024 I get 0.117188.      Can you explain why The Binomial Coefficient of 10     7     is equal to the number of ways to get 7 correct answers?

Comment: @user124645: I can explain it- but it would be a bit long explanation. It would be much easier for you to look up Binomial distributions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: @user124645: You are most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Binomial Distribution to calculate each probability: if she gets 7, 8, 9 or 10 and then add them together. Assuming 50/50, the chances for exactly k out of n would be ${n\choose k} 0.5^k  \ 0.5^{n-k}$ ($p$ and $1-p$ are both 0.5). You can sum them manually or there are cumulative distributive function calculators that will do it for you.